# upload de videos diretamente para o Vimeo com retorno da URL

Tags: java, ios, upload, vimeo-api

Amigos poderiam me ajudar em uma questão onde estou desenvolvendo um app em que faço upload de videos para o servidor, mas estou com problemas na reprodução e armazenamento dos videos, já que estes videos ocupam muito espaço no servidor,  então eu gostaria de fazer o upload de videos através do Vimeo isso me pouparia de ter dores de cabeça, mas baixei vários exemplos e pesquisei muito a respeito, mas não obtive sucesso, alguém teria algum exemplo de upload com objective-c ou através ou java?

Answer (score 1):

O Vimeo tem sua própria API, é muito bem documentada, e com bons exemplos, se souber como criar a integração para realizar o upload, não deve ter muitos problemas.

https://developer.vimeo.com/

https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos

> É uma API REST, então suporta os verbos HTTP necessários para a
>   integração, é preciso ter um REST Client.

Na documentação de duas das implementações do [JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services), existe alguns exemplos para criar um REST Client.

https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Client_Framework

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html

Comment: Sim, eu e minha equipe e alguns amigos estudamos a API deles até entramos em contato com a equipe do Vimeo, mas ninguém conseguiu fazer um upload de video para o Vimeo.

Comment: Por que ninguem conseguiu, ocorreu algum problema?

Comment: Ocorre um erro de permissão.

Comment: Mesmo seguindo a documentação? https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication Também é preciso registrar a aplicação para obter o id e chave https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start